# Using BeautifulSoup to Parse XML to a Dictionary

Tags: xml, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I have a piece of XML that looks like this:

```
 <ns:Vehicle>
  <ns:Model>AVALON</ns:Model>
  <ns:ModelYear>1998</ns:ModelYear>
  <ns:MakeString>TY</ns:MakeString>
  <ns:VehicleID>VIN NUMBER GOES HERE</ns:VehicleID>
 </ns:Vehicle>
```

I have the following code to make the vehicle element into a dictionary:

```
xml_file = open('6046179.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(xml_file)

# Vehicle elements
el_model = soup.find('ns:model').text
el_model_year = soup.find('ns:modelyear').text
el_make_string = soup.find('ns:makestring').text
el_vehicle_id = soup.find('ns:vehicleid').text

vehicle = {'model': '{}'.format(el_model),
           'model_year': '{}'.format(el_model_year),
           'make_string': '{}'.format(el_make_string),
           'vehicle_id': '{}'.format(el_vehicle_id)}

print vehicle
```

I am just wondering if there is a better way to do this, I don't mind going through the rest of the elements in the XML and defining them individually like this, I just would like to know if there is a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be a bit cleaner, but essentially no different:

```
tags = ['model', 'modelyear', 'makestring', 'vehicleid']
vehicle = {}
for tag in tags:
    vehicle[tag] = '{}'.format(soup.find('ns:' + tag).text)
```

There's also [xmltodict](https://github.com/martinblech/xmltodict) that might be worth a look.

Comment: I tried xmltodict and the xml I am working with was a gigantic mess of nested OrderedDict. Thank you for this solution, much cleaner than mine.

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup is not really meant for XML - it's ideal for messy HTML, that would break a proper parser.

You're much better off using [etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) interface (via, perhaps, the very fast [lxml](http://lxml.de/)) which IIRC is what BS uses under the hood by default anyway. Then you get the root element and iterate over all its children in a few lines of code, e.g.:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

# Note the dummy namespace that must / should have been there...
xml = '''
 <ns:Vehicle xmlns:ns="http://foo.bar">
  <ns:Model>AVALON</ns:Model>
  <ns:ModelYear>1998</ns:ModelYear>
  <ns:MakeString>TY</ns:MakeString>
  <ns:VehicleID>VIN NUMBER GOES HERE</ns:VehicleID>
 </ns:Vehicle>'''

tree = ET.fromstring(xml)
vehicle = {re.sub(r'{.*}', '', node.tag): node.text for node in tree}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want *all* the child nodes inside the `<ns:Vehicle>` element, you don't need to explicitly specify them - just loop over all the child elements and put them in a dictionary.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('''
 <ns:Vehicle>
  <ns:Model>AVALON</ns:Model>
  <ns:ModelYear>1998</ns:ModelYear>
  <ns:MakeString>TY</ns:MakeString>
  <ns:VehicleID>VIN NUMBER GOES HERE</ns:VehicleID>
 </ns:Vehicle>
 ''')

# loop if you have multiple vehicles
# Note that BS normalizes all tag names to lowercase -> we use 'ns:vehicle' rather 'ns:Vehicle'
for el_vehicle in soup.find_all('ns:vehicle'): 
    vehicle = {child.name: child.text for child in el_vehicle.findChildren()}
    # stick `vehicle` in a list or do some other processing
```

This doesn't exactly match your output since it doesn't convert from camelcase to underscore-separated names (e.g. `ModelYear` to `model_year`), and it also doesn't strip the namespace off the element names. If you need that, it shouldn't be too difficult to include a wrapper around `child.name` to change the name accordingly.